# NSObject finalize is deprecated - what do I do instead?

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, deprecated, nsobject, finalize

I've been working on some XML utilities in Objective-C, including my own IO stream objects built around `FILE *` values. In order to do this safely it is important that I call `fclose` on the file pointer when the stream object is deallocated (if I had not already done so).

My strategy for this (and many other deallocation tasks) has long been to override the `finalize` method of `NSObject`. However I just read (and confirmed by testing) that `finalize` no longer gets called at all during deallocation.

> Garbage collection is deprecated in OS X v10.8; instead, you should use Automatic Reference Counting—see [*Transitioning to ARC Release Notes*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226).

So apparently I've now been through two versions of OS X without realizing that I was hemorrhaging system resources the whole time. I read through those release notes and I could not find any reference to this particular problem. I was unable to find any alternative method for handling deallocation.

I write Objective-C wrappers for C/C++ data types a lot. I need to some way to release unmanaged memory when the wrapper is being deallocated.

Is there any ARC alternative to `finalize`? And if not what am I supposed to do about malloc'd C/C++ types in my NSObjects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [NSObject class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/dealloc)...

[image]